# Deploying Optimize via GTM or Gtag, which is most performant

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

Givens:
Using Anti-Flicker Snippet, All tags to be deployed via GTM

Question: In the days of analytics.js there was an "analytics-optimize" method of installing Optimize so that optimize could begin loading BEFORE GTM, and not be be dependent on GTM container load / initialization.

See here: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/03/02/updated-instructions-implementing-google-optimize/#3-how-to-install-the-optimize-snippet

this is the important part:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-123456-1', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'GTM-XXXXXX');
</script>
```

If you have not seen this before let me summarize quickly: This loads analytics JS, which in turn loads the optimize container. the ga('send','pageview'); is omitted as the pageview will be sent via GTM ( which is loaded later)

However with the release of gtag.js, is there an updated "Gtag-Optimize" snippet that performs the same function, or is this no longer needed in the GTAG era?

The "analytics-optimize" method was used to load Optimize faster.. is there still a performance-related reason to attempt to load optimize outside GTM, or is loading via GTM the most performant method now?
(or at least performant enough that there is no need to try other methods like "gtag-optimize")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still an option If you deploy it via the gtag solution see reference here https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7513085?hl=en

This will load gtag and the optimize script outside of GTM.

To stop Pageviews set the pageview to false in the gtag code.

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { 'send_page_view': false });
```

Comment: But wont this solution fire a page view from gtag by default?

What I would like to do is create a script that loads optimize ASAP (not waiting for GTM initialize, container download, optimize initialize, optimize container download)

But still control pageviews from GTM...

Comment: Hi There, just set the pageview to false in the gtag code.     gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {     'send_page_view': false });

Comment: Thanks Jessie, missed that bit in the google documentation.
Now just need to test it to see if one method is more performant than the other.